# Need Help Transposing Different Values of the Same Criteria [Difficult to Describe, Example of What I Need Inside]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So let's imagine a table where the same column value appears multiple times, but every time it happens, a value in a different column on each of these rows is different:

| Item | QTY | Box Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mango | 50 | 1 |
| Apple | 100 | 1 |
| Orange | 60 | 2 |
| Mango | 50 | 6 |
| Watermelon | 10 | 3 |
| Mango | 100 | 9 |
| Orange | 150 | 10 |

I want to create another table in another sheet that references this table whereby I want an "Item" column, a "Total QTY" column (using SUMIF to calculate the total number of items pertaining to the fruit on the row), and then for the rest of the columns in the row:

- I want Excel to transpose all the locations that Item is located in along that row.
  Is it possible to use this table to return something like this using Excel functions (without the use of VBA):

| Item | TotalQTY | - | - | - |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 100 | 1 | - | - |
| Mango | 200 | 1 | 6 | 8 |
| Orange | 210 | 2 | 10 | - |
| Watermelon | 10 | 3 | - | - |

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 2):

In my `Excel365` I have used below formulas as per below screenshot.

```
E2=SORT(UNIQUE(A2:A8))
F2=SUMIFS(B2:B8,A2:A8,E2#)
G2=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($C$2:$C$8,$A$2:$A$8=E2))
```

[image]

If you are not using `O365` then could try below. `F2` cell fornula.

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,E2)
```

Then drag down. `G2` cell formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$7)/($A$2:$A$8=$E2),COLUMNS($A$1:A$1))),"")
```

Then drag down and across till need.

Comment: Thank you so much. The "Transpose" and "Filter" function seems to have done the job in my Office 365. However, people who still use the data still use Office 2019. Is it possible to use the same formula with an excel table? I don't know how to use $ signs with Excel Tables and it seems to break the formula for me.

Comment: @D41V30N In case of table you can just use column name. For Excel2019 you can try Aggregate which I already shown on answer.

Comment: I am having trouble with my absolute referencing and column referencing the data when placed within a table. Suppose the first table is called "ORDER_IN" and the second table is called "TOTAL"; how would you go about referencing it?

Comment: @D41V30N Use `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(ORDER_IN[Box Number],ORDER_IN[Item]=[@Item]))` for table. If it is both table then for second table (result table) you have to write formula to each column because FILTER formula can't spill result automatically across table columns.